# relationship between directory structure and packages in golang

Tags: go, package

I am new to Golang and grasp the concept of packages fairly well, but have a question about their relationship to folder/directory location.

So I am working on a fairly large project with multiple subdirectories inside the `/pkg` directory.  There are probably 30+ distinct `package ___` namespaces declared.

Typically of course all files inside of a directory will have the same package, e.g. `/pkg/system/api-client`; all files in that directory are declared `package apiclient`

The question arises when I notice two files of `package config`; one is in `/pkg/config/config.go` and the other is `/pkg/writer-job/pkg/config/config.go`.

Are they part of the same package?  If so, what is the convention for this (as it seems quite scattered)?  And if not, how do you lexically separate `config` as two separate packages?  I did search the docs but don't see this.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/code#Organization — also, two packages may have the same name but different import paths

Comment: Maybe part of the confusion comes from this use of the word "namespaces". Go does not have namespaces. Packages may have names, but the name itself isn't what organizes the code: the package is.

Answer (score 12):

There are two concepts: package name, and import path.

The package name is what you declare with a `package` as the first statement in a go file. A directory can contain at most one package.

An import path is how you import that package, and shows the location of the package. Once you import it, the declared `package` name is used to qualify exported identifiers from that package.

In case of conflicting package names, you define an alias for one of them.

```
import (
   "someproject/pkg/config"
   writerconfig "someproject/pkg/writer-job/config"
)
```

Then, `config.X` refers to the first package, and `writerconfig.X` refers to the second.

Comment: Thank you.  my other question is regarding ` "someproject/pkg/config"` - there may be several files in that directory, all of package `config`.  But can I also have subdirectories with files in them of `package config` ?

Comment: Those would be different packages also named `config`. All files of a package have to be in the same directory.